# How to set startweights in R with neuralnet()?

Tags: r, neural-network

I can't seem to get `neuralnet()` to use desired set of `startweights` in R. It's telling me what it used is different than what I gave it to use. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a look at my data:

```
> summary(traindata)
   Y1               X1               X2               X3               X4               X5               X6               X7        
Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.1127   1st Qu.:0.2966   1st Qu.:0.2364   1st Qu.:0.1000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:0.4871   1st Qu.:0.2769  
 Median :0.2081   Median :0.4602   Median :0.4000   Median :0.1800   Median :1.0000   Median :1.0000   Median :0.5554   Median :0.3684  
 Mean   :0.2266   Mean   :0.4494   Mean   :0.3895   Mean   :0.2058   Mean   :0.5427   Mean   :0.9528   Mean   :0.5572   Mean   :0.3532  
 3rd Qu.:0.3179   3rd Qu.:0.6128   3rd Qu.:0.5455   3rd Qu.:0.2904   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.6261   3rd Qu.:0.4259  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000  
       X8                X9              X10         
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.0400   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:0.07353   1st Qu.:0.3240   1st Qu.:0.08475  
 Median :0.12325   Median :0.3733   Median :0.15254  
 Mean   :0.14481   Mean   :0.3815   Mean   :0.18383  
 3rd Qu.:0.19377   3rd Qu.:0.4308   3rd Qu.:0.25424  
 Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000  
> str(traindata)
'data.frame':   99851 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Y1 : num  0.3295 0.1705 0.0983 0.3526 0.078 ...
 $ X1 : num  0.766 0.234 0.234 0.362 0.447 ...
 $ X2 : num  0.655 0.2 0.2 0.309 0.382 ...
 $ X3 : num  0.68 0.08 0.08 0.2 0.28 0.24 0.16 0.24 0.32 0.68 ...
 $ X4 : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X5 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X6 : num  0.691 0.691 0.691 0.691 0.691 ...
 $ X7 : num  0.516 0.516 0.516 0.516 0.516 ...
 $ X8 : num  0.2941 0 0.0588 0.0588 0.0588 ...
 $ X9 : num  0.587 0.587 0.587 0.587 0.587 ...
 $ X10: num  0.559 0.559 0.559 0.559 0.559 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:10993] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10993] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Here are my first set of weights and their derivation:

```
> nn1 <- neuralnet(as.formula(paste(vars[1], paste(vars[-1], collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")), traindata, hidden = c(10), threshold = 1, rep = 1, linear.output = TRUE, likelihood = TRUE, act.fct = "logistic", err.fct = "sse", learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), lifesign = "full")
hidden: 10    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:    1000   min thresh: 2.7393808337981
                                                 2000   min thresh: 2.12567204477669
                                                 3000   min thresh: 1.13638473824821
                                                 3743   error: 480.83856    aic: 1203.67712 bic: 2354.56067 time: 4.11 mins
> print(nn1$weights)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]
 [1,] -0.2014786  0.18227349  0.42386997  0.4607535 -0.39450924  0.26347907  1.35077384 -0.8789595 -1.3539250 -1.9073238
 [2,] -0.3138759  0.49426852  1.81863245  0.3458816  0.50622031 -0.31646315  0.23761338  1.2262221  0.7223506 -0.2711352
 [3,]  4.9401520 -0.12948452 -0.07537522  0.5795735 -1.29174636  1.84254635 -0.01407708 -0.4445504  0.1804914  1.8145001
 [4,]  5.8923391 -0.04022121  0.13038399 -1.5092823  0.40777519 -1.45995638  1.30011068  1.5655756  0.8829988  1.3954805
 [5,] -2.2528145 -1.38591431 -0.71961962  0.5355580 -3.17343121 -3.07299792  0.39655175  0.3208737 -1.4468927  0.1433068
 [6,] -4.6941619  0.77248242  1.30488285 -0.9680374 -0.23188218 -0.67685608  0.23555409 -0.4077941 -0.8229579 -0.9883259
 [7,]  0.4100560 -0.70637286 -1.88565770  0.8880590  0.91697183 -1.30062889 -0.78349558  0.5051081  0.3398119 -0.3897786
 [8,] -2.4235714  0.46652541  0.91892126  1.2754564  0.07831533 -0.25483017  0.49876237 -0.8897812 -1.0529990  0.1073808
 [9,]  0.6887370 -0.04701979  1.16011774  1.0705425 -0.51051715  3.21512739 -0.16291760  1.9464262  1.1197134  0.9003921
[10,]  0.8101476  1.02021087  0.21620719 -1.2889352 -0.41192141 -0.05808716 -1.42630951 -1.7183708  1.2418989 -0.4668008
[11,]  0.3647498  1.20825730  0.65285143 -0.1963329  0.18026556 -0.05677131 -2.40956470 -1.1985816  2.0340285 -0.7114733

[[1]][[2]]
            [,1]
 [1,] -0.7520664
 [2,] -0.1585614
 [3,]  1.3487849
 [4,] -0.6733687
 [5,]  0.3307345
 [6,] -0.6471139
 [7,] -0.3186048
 [8,]  0.5249488
 [9,]  0.3694480
[10,]  0.5088863
[11,]  0.8333604
```

Finally, I train a second, identical, model using the `weights` from `nn1` as the `startweights` for this one:

```
> nn2 <- neuralnet(as.formula(paste(nn1$model.list$response, paste(nn1$model.list$variables, collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")), traindata, hidden = c(10), threshold = 1, rep = 1, startweights = nn1$weights, linear.output = TRUE, likelihood = TRUE, act.fct = "logistic", err.fct = "sse", learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), lifesign = "full")
hidden: 10    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:    1000   min thresh: 4.57507785044985
                                                 2000   min thresh: 2.08275094219317
                                                 3000   min thresh: 1.81643516394141
                                                 4000   min thresh: 1.38511662675027
                                                 5000   min thresh: 1.2384995622333
                                                 6000   min thresh: 1.05033117773123
                                                 6140   error: 480.46492    aic: 1202.92984 bic: 2353.8134  time: 6.71 mins
> print(nn2$startweights)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]        [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
 [1,]  0.5893646 -0.81292669 -0.5629438  1.51903906 -1.4257453  0.1275882 -0.1057396 -0.05577868  0.22800704 -0.4595900
 [2,]  0.3707842  0.62274320 -0.0422689 -1.34965018 -0.5878436  0.7691974  1.5898764  0.11876721 -0.58689336 -1.1698612
 [3,]  0.6279824  0.22326940  1.7347023  1.51156918  0.2334499  0.3158411  0.4289562 -0.91420679 -0.05893476 -0.1374126
 [4,] -0.9799132 -0.73397255 -0.9325482  0.59750513  0.9198289  0.7040063 -2.0303020  0.06785993 -1.00338522  0.2185066
 [5,]  1.0546680  0.05642049  2.4998288  0.25655327  0.7573550 -0.3371682  0.7030798 -1.72373603 -1.55635173  0.5687848
 [6,] -2.7430174 -0.05536320  0.6252137 -0.42381818 -0.7434616 -0.7051810 -1.8649875 -0.87884095 -1.44110361 -0.9061813
 [7,]  0.6724057 -0.46366009  0.8204684  0.17219848  1.6992790  1.1190887 -0.7160276 -1.84172069 -0.45989825  1.0582524
 [8,] -1.0323476 -1.00524666  0.6220114 -0.04176771 -0.7908566 -1.9329564 -0.4563705  1.35359872  0.97917593 -0.2789364
 [9,]  0.1849783 -0.68836195 -1.1701419  1.91795922  1.1785882 -1.3456765 -0.8279595  0.81416043  0.45596681  0.1533143
[10,] -1.4070175  0.39805001  0.5166913  0.28639229  2.3440190  0.7993813 -1.1532419  0.26576989 -1.25017931 -0.3226559
[11,] -0.9816999 -0.65578411 -1.9905986 -0.45488073 -1.7489129 -0.5705796 -1.4147741 -0.35974793  0.78863263 -0.2901202

[[1]][[2]]
            [,1]
 [1,] -1.9173234
 [2,]  1.3536004
 [3,] -0.3369278
 [4,] -0.5524846
 [5,]  0.3954354
 [6,]  0.1652088
 [7,] -0.9997065
 [8,] -2.9073613
 [9,]  0.4071850
[10,]  1.8160924
[11,] -0.1539692
```

As you can see, the startweights from `nn2` do not match the weights from `nn1`. Why is this the case? Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Hopefully this set of data will be more reproducible. As you can see, the same problem persists, even on a whole new database.

```
> Y1 <- rnorm(100)
> X1 <- rnorm(100)
> X2 <- rnorm(100)
> X3 <- rnorm(100)
> X4 <- rnorm(100)
> X5 <- rnorm(100)
> X6 <- rnorm(100)
> X7 <- rnorm(100)
> X8 <- rnorm(100)
> X9 <- rnorm(100)
> X10 <- rnorm(100)
> traindata <- data.frame(Y1, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10)
> vars <- c("Y1", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")
> #
> summary(traindata)
       Y1                X1                 X2                 X3                X4                 X5                 X6          
 Min.   :-2.6282   Min.   :-2.31081   Min.   :-2.84703   Min.   :-2.9574   Min.   :-3.06652   Min.   :-2.92643   Min.   :-2.68786  
 1st Qu.:-0.8128   1st Qu.:-0.77061   1st Qu.:-0.77318   1st Qu.:-0.8722   1st Qu.:-0.72283   1st Qu.:-0.64498   1st Qu.:-0.84654  
 Median :-0.1805   Median :-0.01352   Median :-0.03076   Median :-0.1707   Median :-0.06016   Median :-0.02921   Median : 0.03849  
 Mean   :-0.1996   Mean   :-0.05143   Mean   :-0.13527   Mean   :-0.1927   Mean   :-0.07680   Mean   :-0.06514   Mean   :-0.01596  
 3rd Qu.: 0.5022   3rd Qu.: 0.62631   3rd Qu.: 0.57501   3rd Qu.: 0.4927   3rd Qu.: 0.48539   3rd Qu.: 0.57380   3rd Qu.: 0.68568  
 Max.   : 2.0202   Max.   : 2.06222   Max.   : 2.30610   Max.   : 1.8968   Max.   : 2.76293   Max.   : 2.37159   Max.   : 2.51357  
       X7                 X8                 X9                X10          
 Min.   :-2.76740   Min.   :-2.21274   Min.   :-2.25566   Min.   :-3.18281  
 1st Qu.:-0.56095   1st Qu.:-0.66163   1st Qu.:-0.53334   1st Qu.:-0.82798  
 Median :-0.01693   Median : 0.03079   Median : 0.04594   Median :-0.09057  
 Mean   :-0.02820   Mean   : 0.02596   Mean   : 0.13564   Mean   :-0.21482  
 3rd Qu.: 0.67220   3rd Qu.: 0.59838   3rd Qu.: 0.73141   3rd Qu.: 0.43741  
 Max.   : 1.82162   Max.   : 2.81257   Max.   : 2.56385   Max.   : 2.15635  
> str(traindata)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Y1 : num  0.7019 -0.7081 0.0401 -1.4108 0.0186 ...
 $ X1 : num  1.2737 -0.4937 0.8092 1.6592 0.0524 ...
 $ X2 : num  0.5711 1.1013 1.5813 0.0494 -1.4142 ...
 $ X3 : num  -2.1977 0.0186 0.013 -0.7717 -0.024 ...
 $ X4 : num  0.478 -0.193 -0.918 0.674 0.654 ...
 $ X5 : num  0.481 0.392 0.411 -1.211 -1.801 ...
 $ X6 : num  1.4 -0.783 1.57 -1.658 -1.214 ...
 $ X7 : num  0.202 0.387 1.601 -0.279 0.366 ...
 $ X8 : num  -0.5429 2.8126 -0.0973 -0.7661 -2.1521 ...
 $ X9 : num  1.6332 -0.0177 -1.6318 0.9238 -1.8879 ...
 $ X10: num  -0.472 -0.089 0.488 -3.183 0.775 ...
> nn1 <- neuralnet(as.formula(paste(vars[1], paste(vars[-1], collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")), traindata, hidden = c(10), threshold = 1, rep = 1, linear.output = TRUE, likelihood = TRUE, act.fct = "logistic", err.fct = "sse", learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), lifesign = "full")
hidden: 10    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:      73   error: 3.87651  aic: 249.75302  bic: 564.97861  time: 0.03 secs
> print(nn1$weights)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
 [1,]  2.0561478  2.1246898 -1.76213815 -0.9579672  1.7365645 -3.6917655 -2.8679099 -2.3354355 -0.78416048 -0.8883347
 [2,] -1.1735772  0.6258137 -1.59676588  0.5743075 -4.1081508  1.2250868 -2.2711916  2.6963711 -2.85434918  0.1391520
 [3,]  1.6164354 -0.1167470 -1.86684971 -3.5957692  0.6213768 -2.0814941  1.5481369 -0.4647491 -1.71029782  1.0826877
 [4,] -0.6293219 -0.6560375 -1.35948106 -1.5444962 -4.4668895  0.2072900 -0.5671789 -1.5835564  2.48531032 -1.6700781
 [5,]  2.0008226 -5.5525417 -0.01907481 -4.2084540  1.5691657 -0.6965300  0.3713269  0.6354120 -0.50617525 -5.9433049
 [6,] -1.2389025 -0.8341130 -3.46508109 -0.4022277 -0.8010767 -1.6026804  0.6800117 -0.4354258  2.87640948 -1.6238975
 [7,]  1.1897863 -1.7753309  3.74799195 -1.3946734  2.4358772  0.5671369  0.8298011 -2.4104047  3.81490744  0.2342864
 [8,] -2.8655656  1.7017802 -2.90380747  1.1301706 -1.4243256  0.3095138  0.7930108  2.8188700 -0.03151904 -0.1262049
 [9,]  1.1732202  0.8257122 -2.47857455  1.9630549 -3.1291087  3.4779904 -0.2160225  0.4892494 -0.73072162  0.4053342
[10,] -3.6661128  0.5989946 -0.88542239  2.9123770  1.1520419 -0.8132918 -3.4014543 -0.2657552 -1.42833485 -1.7101058
[11,]  1.5582244  0.2356327 -0.05400474  0.8694207 -1.4107504  2.5518053  2.0864136 -1.3973193 -0.71283726  4.1963821

[[1]][[2]]
            [,1]
 [1,]  0.9961668
 [2,] -0.7378463
 [3,] -0.8060499
 [4,]  1.0650543
 [5,]  1.4801685
 [6,] -1.1207186
 [7,] -1.0321750
 [8,]  2.2744946
 [9,] -0.8224604
[10,] -0.9745411
[11,] -0.8840396


> nn2 <- neuralnet(as.formula(paste(nn1$model.list$response, paste(nn1$model.list$variables, collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")), traindata, hidden = c(10), threshold = 1, rep = 1, startweights = nn1$weights, linear.output = TRUE, likelihood = TRUE, act.fct = "logistic", err.fct = "sse", learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), lifesign = "full")
hidden: 10    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:      72   error: 4.43824  aic: 250.87649  bic: 566.10208  time: 0.03 secs
> print(nn2$startweights)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]         [,5]        [,6]       [,7]        [,8]        [,9]         [,10]
 [1,] -1.69644421 -0.4333522 -1.30154641  0.4536848  0.291446600  0.67304726  1.1416902  2.38808056  0.83386911 -0.0009094806
 [2,]  1.61174965  1.9336793 -1.15244916 -1.0842433 -0.150961924 -1.33579414  1.7830017 -1.00851612 -0.04383156 -0.1297548803
 [3,] -0.06963176  0.9042027 -0.48823105  0.7636997  1.603469276  0.14116076 -0.2406283 -1.41095608 -0.88344106  0.7069823815
 [4,]  1.54570246  1.1687791  1.23740145  1.3748013 -1.299009433  0.18957076  1.0178625  0.79229782 -1.49661956 -0.5379553541
 [5,]  0.41870651  0.7305606  0.01583256 -0.6306494  0.562912456 -0.30008432  1.8717705  0.42124102 -0.15980324  0.2513703357
 [6,]  1.16461680  2.0595952 -0.76574309 -0.1111576  2.220310268  0.75662937  1.2029788 -0.39538609  0.49934000  2.0005942684
 [7,]  0.15716435 -0.2566108 -1.27468440 -0.5930131  0.818792043  0.66329768  0.7452777 -0.03777932  1.20430254 -0.5595158877
 [8,] -1.58467560  1.4673691 -0.83996793 -0.4187563  0.705109624 -1.24442801  0.1704734 -0.58777674 -0.40027652 -2.4756589392
 [9,] -0.89337191  0.6316128 -0.82507999  1.5183803 -0.287585827 -2.41368786  2.1250179  0.12195748 -1.53103716  0.4412285905
[10,] -0.01346646  0.7372053  1.49649858 -1.9613378 -0.003319936 -0.79324517  3.2320651 -0.16751147  0.90642655  0.6876876521
[11,]  0.28453268 -0.3871505 -0.41599417  1.5926093 -0.662442433 -0.02527895 -0.4075339  0.29115879 -0.43122825 -1.5403539978

[[1]][[2]]
            [,1]
 [1,]  0.3947711
 [2,]  0.4984659
 [3,] -0.8605949
 [4,]  0.2138002
 [5,] -0.7624599
 [6,] -0.2855559
 [7,] -1.7123571
 [8,] -0.9662195
 [9,] -0.5196383
[10,]  0.3078660
[11,] -1.0751191
```

Here is an exact sample of this randomly generated dataset:

```
> dput(head(traindata, 30))
structure(list(Y1 = c(0.701922182356232, -0.708123531581225, 
0.0400587622254783, -1.41080737945381, 0.0185917925803016, -0.756094808213198, 
0.229827153393527, 1.03359044931556, -0.325979966122, 1.94639172458108, 
-0.0858880338034102, 1.30192478542873, -1.29456974769679, 0.424863652008442, 
0.137431331087742, 0.967718619114868, 0.712884633842502, 1.09660017836771, 
1.42251489219274, -1.3932494645714, 0.132517063221073, -0.586773257455408, 
-1.04867834765241, -1.48298842777259, -1.18811202193506, -0.0764177818781156, 
0.749556896109999, -1.3529282263906, -0.199434984963032, -0.670278221235389
), X1 = c(1.27366502736629, -0.493684689890589, 0.809158629404917, 
1.65915843651466, 0.0524406431564457, 1.99834071163273, -2.31081184205956, 
-1.17120485025769, -0.993257451630739, 0.153530041415676, 0.131742575531519, 
1.0854692238377, -1.22117812015096, 1.20784952618741, -1.60309580657283, 
0.275992514430696, 0.465355658798675, -0.58324043244759, -0.110548854772808, 
0.714089052476505, 0.8291456053507, -0.19349333985983, 0.503401775891749, 
0.334556651206673, -0.119878011897093, 0.195156112996898, 0.0636604084639662, 
1.34475958603765, -0.355289744059907, -0.960344976220009), X2 = c(0.571072453624444, 
1.1013233917443, 1.58134119122358, 0.0494181005667735, -1.41424073791614, 
-0.317851997994474, -0.124667161289762, 0.845029910205487, -1.1392281731113, 
-2.84702736919688, -0.321182929319084, -0.612686484466993, 0.272155530547179, 
-2.06371852987761, -0.484717082770012, 1.10674403379459, -1.2154536411017, 
0.258139113555222, -0.761462644039399, -0.179388697566508, -0.457896931695907, 
-0.317076825483547, -1.52671258748914, -0.931004767208564, 1.04596630098729, 
0.563468202434267, -0.46893437559372, 1.28328427263904, 0.356878807333198, 
-0.714834159650127), X3 = c(-2.19767598984247, 0.0185884088546519, 
0.0129525883347238, -0.771733202114285, -0.0239773350187926, 
0.778822293534904, -0.443666145403694, -1.23534078334349, -0.621178446436027, 
1.07558407906203, 0.184032149735252, -0.396860023019889, 0.989731378110675, 
0.593591189965602, -0.631541708619503, -1.38424024942674, 0.199560535550159, 
0.58295391877909, 0.306646068780785, -0.214125096089182, 0.211904502773658, 
1.18389005375035, 0.479384174006876, -1.57515519003181, -0.950589131657951, 
0.570587858431722, 0.770643652985999, -0.0781891019601696, 0.165283974675214, 
-0.482431104312909), X4 = c(0.47762074365917, -0.19280124334945, 
-0.917797642044604, 0.673904599272376, 0.654197442468486, -0.0697760044808261, 
2.27076384456501, 0.679999811887382, 0.508491060290448, 1.16295246888786, 
-0.445411117332417, -0.325811531846809, 1.50163109930028, 1.83535005124084, 
0.47586332354473, 1.87962386913725, 0.870235116234204, 0.411485039619166, 
-1.35871567422559, 0.0076564730844747, 1.06777549450363, 1.50987449933043, 
0.213161153472195, 0.186115557477568, -0.157791280579259, -1.23709397773273, 
-0.0505373473885883, -1.00068684118648, 0.287353480148877, 0.830433773553478
), X5 = c(0.481174226063212, 0.391844037883607, 0.410876615099086, 
-1.21147781618028, -1.80075974845901, 0.800546029642124, -0.476361769636676, 
-0.944402072158152, -0.79949012101078, 0.615609119547131, -0.332089606424653, 
-1.28611162784317, -0.126324999116017, -0.850079074926488, -1.16303552579073, 
1.11694000035649, -0.642213432814981, -0.428477829678032, 0.270059019091907, 
0.578167082173589, -0.961260659353575, 1.01356399631725, -0.434149676049041, 
0.454191770775709, 0.945539987554406, -0.653287973061059, 0.975212345830591, 
-2.92643275651569, 0.131537200351334, -0.144696759170823), X6 = c(1.39986578192177, 
-0.783303464282605, 1.57043416479322, -1.65818976109745, -1.21385993362988, 
-1.26704173775851, 0.483189914381612, 0.683337644958036, 1.79018891817461, 
-0.0110654691673887, -0.32034328626619, 1.47261067198678, -0.0630799680643052, 
-1.35355116067763, -0.0892303482657638, 0.669675744222314, 1.13749863964793, 
0.468890086305808, -1.56688842791645, 1.29022138572065, -1.34920827872719, 
-0.825007844187256, 0.237314361839962, 1.53662062038759, 1.20652616894649, 
-1.1377851987682, 0.773646609261767, 0.94323579506706, 0.420605406590486, 
0.0657302585327347), X7 = c(0.201587687432359, 0.387221536601237, 
1.60114696197582, -0.278897031389238, 0.365790676008811, -0.993046118293481, 
1.62143648572453, 0.665967320401928, 0.994410345825827, -0.170991304653852, 
-0.227964877787297, -0.486532886674193, 0.042032489279269, 0.824612159718666, 
-0.642117241988523, 0.312476614136496, -1.03961891897275, -0.548667354933751, 
-0.0521273232669943, 1.51521890875494, 1.51535213926008, 0.253539571229083, 
0.64234449708054, 1.04420862461711, 1.53756512387198, -1.26057851363841, 
0.742294745891574, -1.42184455296825, 0.587000367973472, -0.349451731018588
), X8 = c(-0.542914358047845, 2.81257202395158, -0.0972695380162739, 
-0.7661342677977, -2.15214352701854, 0.946717716211487, 0.99993003028658, 
0.614546386898964, -0.859811405490715, -0.670453616234801, -0.17346947446889, 
-1.07727894279311, 0.592312115423768, -0.256019200500554, 0.319958459484677, 
0.321687427347929, 1.98242781790999, -0.846064232318548, -0.736994211412997, 
-0.115411197421152, -0.754459840834644, -0.456395622597785, 0.74266667766863, 
0.968610205824152, -0.72767394430833, -0.0482633104925355, 0.51270022238816, 
-0.621368764086511, -0.0138749896213129, -0.658688294139246), 
    X9 = c(1.63317823978059, -0.01774256677172, -1.63177241040162, 
    0.923776797289243, -1.88791456589611, 0.532970416239549, 
    -0.311699268395948, 2.43527710160233, 0.038332347572289, 
    0.264960926473119, -1.08530924957301, 1.24640634922912, -0.116226724474104, 
    -0.0224132482158086, -0.0169490420992843, 0.311908689778931, 
    0.729741399504258, -0.562042837815365, 0.344104286394718, 
    -0.630555188617343, 0.779501553691767, 2.56384810481512, 
    -0.406218268893801, 0.825111666168507, 0.86430780344585, 
    -1.05849420512847, 0.473063258062104, -0.523766744743483, 
    -1.28900820575187, 0.322806836954206), X10 = c(-0.471741246765894, 
    -0.0890225241186955, 0.487785473582504, -3.18280694963509, 
    0.775294242648606, 0.908032736784392, -0.870849535156648, 
    -1.8729895069865, -0.924248866769357, 0.064378071447313, 
    0.396570183961503, -0.62260644614774, -1.55366000366709, 
    1.3514088664078, -1.06920245196414, 0.521276074417584, -0.413882376032191, 
    0.17396816534063, 0.601746726940767, 0.797912945936916, -0.254266428410621, 
    -1.37234718769371, 0.133105253457835, 0.387347519836891, 
    0.133134442347685, -0.541749317358317, 0.129941549831559, 
    -0.235276238863235, -1.19889658129318, -0.45975918808316)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hi @DataProphets, you could also share a sample using `dput(head(df, 30))` for example.

Comment: Even `dput(head(df, 30))`, indeed even `dput(head(df, 1))`  prints out more than my screen can display. Let me try it again with a new database whose generation can be reproduced. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's check what the argument `startweights` mean:

> a vector containing starting values for the weights. Set to NULL for
> random initialization.

So this says that it should contain a **vector** of the weights. What does the model output of "weights" according to document:

> a list containing the fitted weights of the neural network for every
> repetition.

So the first problem is that the weights assigned to the second model should be `unlist`. Another thing to keep is mind that the "startweights" are randomly assigned if you don't give weights. To fix this you could use a `set.seed`. Here a reproducible example:

```r
library(neuralnet)
# First model has no startweights which means random weights
set.seed(1)
nn1 <- neuralnet(Y1 ~., data = traindata, hidden = c(10),
          threshold = 1, rep = 1, linear.output = TRUE, 
          likelihood = TRUE, act.fct = "logistic", err.fct = "sse", 
          learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), 
          lifesign = "full")
#> hidden: 10    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:      17    error: 1.89992  aic: 245.79983  bic: 415.34472  time: 0.01 secs

nn1$weights
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#>             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]        [,6]
#>  [1,] -0.7227675  1.2573204 -0.03581002  0.04368123 -1.5562328  0.96199990
#>  [2,] -0.4847567 -0.2692571 -1.98935170 -1.98953668  0.8925048 -1.64922148
#>  [3,] -2.4356286 -0.9326999 -0.22842225 -0.39146624  0.2601260 -2.31253463
#>  [4,]  1.6077579 -0.2250691 -1.45612874  0.34318717 -0.4814671  0.94907976
#>  [5,]  0.6814913 -0.3509336 -0.15109551  0.27767013 -1.3807462 -0.94753172
#>  [6,]  0.7795316 -0.2249663 -1.99415238  0.63162537  0.5441242  3.27001776
#>  [7,]  1.0999062  1.4993562 -0.13079006 -0.50522425  0.9845059 -1.30764000
#>  [8,]  0.9048786  1.6336983  2.01794156 -0.81200072  0.6563736  1.77973936
#>  [9,]  1.9257814  0.2853293  1.41354955 -0.33146952  1.0095197 -0.03261211
#> [10,]  0.6288116  0.3259574  0.63801227  0.69449410 -0.7977631  0.52512679
#> [11,]  0.5333812  1.5946134 -0.96232839  0.21967967  2.0455008 -0.11171042
#>             [,7]        [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
#>  [1,] -3.0733586  0.07785035  0.06689381 -1.7418006
#>  [2,]  1.3927334  0.88681844  1.33549879  0.4480333
#>  [3,]  1.4216533 -0.56786495 -1.81092003  0.1195839
#>  [4,]  1.9902517  0.04380839  0.53946781 -0.6588192
#>  [5,]  0.5065405  0.13220711  0.09200262 -1.1103712
#>  [6,] -0.3253608  0.25968700  0.17773653 -0.9760197
#>  [7,] -0.9892736 -2.13604392  1.78431057  1.2382873
#>  [8,] -0.4024976 -0.67445381  1.47688643  1.5841846
#>  [9,]  0.3463666  0.38295037 -2.21339221  0.5597742
#> [10,]  0.4914462  2.66309984 -0.57522941 -1.2158146
#> [11,] -1.1532919 -0.11150264 -2.03708973  2.5682161
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#>             [,1]
#>  [1,] -0.3389621
#>  [2,] -0.3848997
#>  [3,]  1.4422322
#>  [4,] -0.8231826
#>  [5,]  0.6600964
#>  [6,] -0.4152942
#>  [7,] -0.3007173
#>  [8,] -0.4515996
#>  [9,]  0.5973076
#> [10,] -0.1580549
#> [11,] -0.6659437

# Second model 
nn2 <- neuralnet(Y1~., data = traindata, hidden = c(10), 
                 threshold = 1, rep = 1, startweights = unlist(nn1$weights), 
                 linear.output = TRUE, likelihood = TRUE, act.fct = "logistic", 
                 err.fct = "sse", learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), 
                 lifesign = "full")
#> hidden: 10    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:       1    error: 1.89992  aic: 245.79983  bic: 415.34472  time: 0 secs

nn2$startweights
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#>             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]        [,6]
#>  [1,] -0.7227675  1.2573204 -0.03581002  0.04368123 -1.5562328  0.96199990
#>  [2,] -0.4847567 -0.2692571 -1.98935170 -1.98953668  0.8925048 -1.64922148
#>  [3,] -2.4356286 -0.9326999 -0.22842225 -0.39146624  0.2601260 -2.31253463
#>  [4,]  1.6077579 -0.2250691 -1.45612874  0.34318717 -0.4814671  0.94907976
#>  [5,]  0.6814913 -0.3509336 -0.15109551  0.27767013 -1.3807462 -0.94753172
#>  [6,]  0.7795316 -0.2249663 -1.99415238  0.63162537  0.5441242  3.27001776
#>  [7,]  1.0999062  1.4993562 -0.13079006 -0.50522425  0.9845059 -1.30764000
#>  [8,]  0.9048786  1.6336983  2.01794156 -0.81200072  0.6563736  1.77973936
#>  [9,]  1.9257814  0.2853293  1.41354955 -0.33146952  1.0095197 -0.03261211
#> [10,]  0.6288116  0.3259574  0.63801227  0.69449410 -0.7977631  0.52512679
#> [11,]  0.5333812  1.5946134 -0.96232839  0.21967967  2.0455008 -0.11171042
#>             [,7]        [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
#>  [1,] -3.0733586  0.07785035  0.06689381 -1.7418006
#>  [2,]  1.3927334  0.88681844  1.33549879  0.4480333
#>  [3,]  1.4216533 -0.56786495 -1.81092003  0.1195839
#>  [4,]  1.9902517  0.04380839  0.53946781 -0.6588192
#>  [5,]  0.5065405  0.13220711  0.09200262 -1.1103712
#>  [6,] -0.3253608  0.25968700  0.17773653 -0.9760197
#>  [7,] -0.9892736 -2.13604392  1.78431057  1.2382873
#>  [8,] -0.4024976 -0.67445381  1.47688643  1.5841846
#>  [9,]  0.3463666  0.38295037 -2.21339221  0.5597742
#> [10,]  0.4914462  2.66309984 -0.57522941 -1.2158146
#> [11,] -1.1532919 -0.11150264 -2.03708973  2.5682161
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#>             [,1]
#>  [1,] -0.3389621
#>  [2,] -0.3848997
#>  [3,]  1.4422322
#>  [4,] -0.8231826
#>  [5,]  0.6600964
#>  [6,] -0.4152942
#>  [7,] -0.3007173
#>  [8,] -0.4515996
#>  [9,]  0.5973076
#> [10,] -0.1580549
#> [11,] -0.6659437
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As you can see, the weights of nn1 are the same as the startweights of nn2.